# How can read message from rabbit and return boolean value?

Tags: java, c#, rabbitmq

I have built this code to sender message from client Java and C# by using rabbit.
So I have this:

```
public Boolean isNaoConnect()
{
    bool isConnect = false;
    string azione = "checkNAO.java:&&{";
    //immetto i parametri di tipo stringa
    azione += "}&&{";
    //parametri di tipo int
    azione += "}&&";
    var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(azione);
    channel.BasicPublish("", "ASTRO", null, messageBody);

    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channelResponse);
    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
    {
    var body = ea.Body;
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    if (message != null && message.Equals("true"))
        isConnect= true;

    };
    channelResponse.BasicConsume(queue: "ASTRO_RESPONSE", noAck: true, consumer: consumer);

    Console.ReadLine();

    return isConnect;
}
```

If the client Java send the message true, the method isNaoConnect should return true else false.
Now I can read the message but I can't return true or false with this code.
How can I fix it?